# Minimizing $\|(I-\alpha H)^2 A\|$?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Is there something in Mathematica that can find $\alpha$ solving minimization problem below, where $A$ and $H$ are positive definite matrices?

$$\|(I-\alpha H)^2 A\|$$

It comes down to finding the smallest circle that encloses an ellipse defined by corresponding quadratic form. For the matrices below, $\alpha\approx 3.2$

$$\text{H=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
\text{A=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 9 \\
 9 & 11 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The code below expressed it through semidefinite constraint, having $\alpha^2$ in the objective makes `SemidefiniteProgramming` inapplicable

$$\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{\alpha,t}\ & t \\
\text{subject to } & 
A-\alpha AH - \alpha HA + \alpha^2 HAH^T \prec t I
\end{align}$$

[image]

For simultaneously diagonalizable $H,A$ with eigenvalues $\{a_i\},\{h_i\}$, it seems to be

```
alphaStart = .1;
alphaEnd = .5;
numSteps = 5;

d = 2;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
H = DiagonalMatrix[{4, 1}];
A = DiagonalMatrix[{10, 1}];
A = With[{rot = RotationMatrix[Pi/4]}, 
   2 rot . A . Inverse[rot] // Simplify];
Print["H=", H // MatrixForm];
Print["A=", A // MatrixForm];


(* Structure as minimization with semidefinite constraint, fails *)
Print[StringForm[
   "Minimizing ||(I-``\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)``||", 
   MatrixForm[H], MatrixForm[A]]];
cons = VectorLessEqual[{(ii - alpha H) . A . (ii - alpha H), 
    t ii}, {"SemidefiniteCone", d}];
SemidefiniteOptimization[ t, {cons}, {t, alpha}];

Clear[mat, alpha];
mat[alpha_] = (ii - alpha H) . A . (ii - alpha H);
curvePlot = 
  Plot[Norm@mat@alpha, {alpha, alphaStart, alphaEnd}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 12}];
genPlot[alpha_] := (
   mat0 = mat@alpha;
   R = Norm@mat0;
   ii = IdentityMatrix[2];
   bound = 3;
   curvePositionPlot = 
    ListPlot[{{alpha, Norm@mat0}}, Filling -> Axis, 
     PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], FillingStyle -> Dashed];
   boundsPlot = 
    ContourPlot[{{x1, x2} . PseudoInverse[mat0] . {x1, x2} == 
       1, {x1, x2} . ii . {x1, x2} == R}, {x1, -bound, 
      bound}, {x2, -bound, bound}, Frame -> False];
   curvePlot0 = Show[curvePlot, curvePositionPlot];
   GraphicsRow[{boundsPlot, curvePlot0}]
   );
plots = Table[
   genPlot[t], {t, alphaStart, 
    alphaEnd, (alphaEnd - alphaStart)/numSteps}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

Comment: Why not use ``Minimize``? ``Minimize[Refine[Norm[(ii - a H) . A . (ii - a H)], 
  a \[Element] Reals], a]`` returns $\alpha \approx  0.309$.

Comment: indeed that works....I was curious if a more specialized solver would work here (since they scale better for large A) but Minimize seems like a good fall-back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a [trick](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/41791/18786) to rewrite it by using Schur's complement and then apply `SemidefiniteOptimization`. It's about 50 times faster than `Minimize`

[image]

```
d = 2;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
H = DiagonalMatrix[{4, 1}];
A = DiagonalMatrix[{10, 1}];
A = With[{rot = RotationMatrix[Pi/4]}, 
   2 rot . A . Inverse[rot] // Simplify];
Print["H=", H // MatrixForm];
Print["A=", A // MatrixForm];

mat[alpha_] = (ii - alpha H) . A . (ii - alpha H)\[Transpose];

sol1 = NMinimize[Norm@mat@alpha, alpha];
point = {alpha /. Last@sol1, First@sol1};
R = CholeskyDecomposition[H . A . H\[Transpose]];
metric = ii;
M = ArrayFlatten[{{t metric - A + alpha (H . A + A . H\[Transpose]), 
     alpha R\[Transpose]}, {alpha R, ii}}];
cons = VectorGreaterEqual[{M, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}];
sol2 = SemidefiniteOptimization[t, {cons}, {t, alpha}]

curvePlot = 
 Plot[Norm@mat@alpha, {alpha, alphaStart, alphaEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 12}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[point]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"alpha", "t"}]
```