# Minimizing linear function subject to quadratic constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

What's the most efficient way to solve the following quadratically constrained linear objective in Mathematica?

$$\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{\alpha,t}\ & t \\
\text{subject to } & a_i(1-\alpha h_i)^2 < t \ \forall i
\end{align}$$

There's `QuadraticOptimization` function, but it does the converse -- linearly constrained quadratic objective.

Here's an example where you can see the minimum is between 1 and 1.5

```
d = 2;
avals = Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}];
hvals = Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}];
Plot[Max[(1 - alpha hvals)^2 avals], {alpha, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

**Motivation**

This is equivalent to [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272258/minimizing-i-alpha-h2-a) in the case of simultaneously diagonalizable $A,H$

```
d = 2;
A = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}]];
 H = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}]];
Plot[Norm[MatrixPower[IdentityMatrix[d] - alpha H, 2] . A], {alpha, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( * Minimize or NMinimize *)
sol = Minimize[{Max[(1 - alpha hvals)^2 avals], 
   0 <= alpha <= 2}, {alpha}]
Plot[Max[(1 - alpha hvals)^2 avals], {alpha, 0, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Point[{alpha, Max[(1 - alpha hvals)^2 avals]} /. sol[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok looks like this scales to thousands of dimensions, Minimize is pretty smart at removing redundant constraints